# Hibernate user messages relation

Tags: java, hibernate, one-to-many, hibernate-onetomany, mappedby

How to create next type of relation in Hibernate entity classes?
User sends message to another user by creating message (sender, receiver, message). DB looks like this:

```
+-----------------------------------+
|                user               |
+-----------------------------------+
| id |   nickname  |    password    |
+----+-------------+----------------+
|  1 |    admin    |      pass      |
+----+-------------+----------------+

+------------------------------------------------+
|                     message                    |
+-----------------------------------|------------+
| id |  sender_id  |  receiver_id   |  message_t |
+----+-------------+----------------+------------+
|  1 |      10     |       12       |      hi    |
+----+-------------+----------------+------------+
```

How entity classes must be look like?

```
@Entity 
@Table(name="profiles")
public class Message {

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "sender")
    private User sender;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "receiver")
    private User receiver;

    @Column(name = "message")
    String message;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = )
    List<Message> messages;
}
```

Mapped by.. what? I need to find all messages, where current user exists as a sender OR/AND receiver. ("AND" because user can sends a message to himself).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you need to find messages sended or recived by user you alread have all information in Message entity and user mapping doesn't matter for you.

> select m from Message m where m.sender!=m.receiver and (m.sender=:user  or
>   m.receiver=:user).

there are two type on relationship: unidirectional and bidirectional.

if in entity mapping for user you should keep information about sender and reciver  (you already have this information in Message) then dibirectional relationship:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = receiver)
    private List<Message> messagesRecived;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = sender)
    private List<Message> messagesSended;
}
```